# Messages about invalid attributes in /etc/fonts/conf.d

Tags: fonts, syslog

I installed Ubuntu 21.10 and changed from gnome desktop to mate desktop. Now I get the following type of messages in /var/logs/syslog. How can I get rid of them?

```
Jan 10 15:34:40 media rtkit-daemon[1738]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jan 10 15:34:40 media rtkit-daemon[1738]: message repeated 2 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.]
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Jan 10 15:34:40 media skypeforlinux.desktop[3874]: Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
```

My /etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf looks like this (I haven't changed in manually):

```
  1 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  2 <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
  3 <fontconfig>
  4   <its:rules xmlns:its="http://www.w3.org/2005/11/its" version="1.0">
  5     <its:translateRule translate="no" selector="/fontconfig/*[not(self::description)]"/>
  6   </its:rules>
  7 
  8   <description>Set preferable fonts for emoji/math fonts</description>
  9 <!-- Keep in sync with 45-generic.conf -->
 10 
 11 <!-- Emoji -->
 12 
 13         <!-- Prefer to match color emoji font. -->
 14         <match>
 15                 <test name="lang">
 16                         <string>und-zsye</string>
 17                 </test>
 18                 <test qual="all" name="color" compare="not_eq">
 19                         <bool>true</bool>
 20                 </test>
 21                 <test qual="all" name="color" compare="not_eq">
 22                         <bool>false</bool>
 23                 </test>
 24                 <edit name="color" mode="append">
 25                         <bool>true</bool>
 26                 </edit>
 27         </match>
 28 
 29         <!-- TODO
 30          ! Match on "color" and alias B&W ones first if no color is requested.
 31          ! That's "hard" because <alias> doesn't work in match and needs to be
 32          ! expanded to its non-sugar form.
 33          !-->
 34         <alias binding="same">
 35                 <family>emoji</family>
 36                 <prefer>
 37                         <!-- System fonts -->
 38                         <family>Noto Color Emoji</family> <!-- Google -->
 39                         <family>Apple Color Emoji</family> <!-- Apple -->
 40                         <family>Segoe UI Emoji</family> <!-- Microsoft -->
 41                         <family>Twitter Color Emoji</family> <!-- Twitter -->
 42                         <family>EmojiOne Mozilla</family> <!-- Mozilla -->
 43                         <!-- Third-Party fonts -->
 44                         <family>Emoji Two</family>
 45                         <family>Emoji One</family>
 46                         <!-- Non-color -->
 47                         <family>Noto Emoji</family> <!-- Google -->
 48                         <family>Android Emoji</family> <!-- Google -->
 49                 </prefer>
 50         </alias>
 51 
 52 <!-- Math -->
 53         <alias binding="same">
 54                 <!-- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematical_OpenType_typefaces -->
 55                 <family>math</family>
 56                 <prefer>
 57                         <family>XITS Math</family> <!-- Khaled Hosny -->
 58                         <family>STIX Two Math</family> <!-- AMS -->
 59                         <family>Cambria Math</family> <!-- Microsoft -->
 60                         <family>Latin Modern Math</family> <!-- TeX -->
 61                         <family>Minion Math</family> <!-- Adobe -->
 62                         <family>Lucida Math</family> <!-- Adobe -->
 63                         <family>Asana Math</family>
 64                 </prefer>
 65         </alias>
 66 
 67 </fontconfig>
```

Comment: I see it's Skype for Linux which complains. Did you possibly install that program via a snap? If so, I would suggest that you try to replace it with Skype for Linux DEB.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I installed it using snap. Ok I'll try your suggestion

Comment: Hi @GunnarHjalmarsson, now I get messages like this "Jan 10 17:54:12 media skypeforlinux.desktop[4320]: [4320:0110/175412.571953:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(349)] Failed to recv from netlink socket: Permission denied (13)". I think there are thousands (it's actually eating all free space on my root partition). Do you have any Idea, how I could fix this?

Comment: Did you run `snap remove skypeforlinux` to remove the snap?

Comment: Hi @Gunnar, yes I performed "snap remove skypeforlinux"

Comment: Then I don't know. I have Skype for Linux (DEB) on 21.10 myself, and have not encountered the error message you mention in a comment.

Comment: Hmm thank you. Probably something went wrong when I switched to mate and changed my installation. When I have time I try to reinstall ubuntu, because I also have some strange behavior of CUDA some times.